# Proof for using approximation coefficient to convert one function into another

Tags: calculus, integration

I watched a video recently which used the formula $$C_k=\frac{\int f_1(t)f_2(t)dt}{\int f_2(t)^2dt}$$ given that

$$f_1(t) = C_k  f_2(t)$$

$C_k$ is a coefficent that can convert any real function into another real function, which is incredibly useful. However I could not figure out how it was derived. What is the proof for this?

Here is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JayFh5EJHcU) that I am referring to.

Comment: Can you please put a reference to the video in the question? Hard to comment on something that is hidden from our view.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I added a link to the video

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a practice in programming, not in Mathematics.

Comment: @jjagmath Fixed, thank you

Comment: That bit of the video is indeed extremely obscure and I would say misleading. In your place, I would look for better videos, or just search for "Fourier series". You cannot "convert any real function into another real function", especially not by multiplying with a constant. What you *can* do is to approximate a real function with a *linear combination* of other functions, choosing the coefficients to get as close to your function as possible. If those "other" functions are monomials $x^k, k\in\mathbb N$, we are talking about *polynomial* approximation. However...

Comment: ... if those functions are $\cos(n\omega x)$ and $\sin(n\omega x)$ for some $\omega$, and your function is periodic with the period $2\pi/\omega$, then we are talking about Fourier approximation. There is quite a bit to learn and understand about this, so please find better sources/books/articles, even videos (why not?).

Comment: For a popular introduction, see e.g. 3blue1brown's video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6sGWTCMz2k